# Android padding between textviews programmatically

Tags: android, textview, padding

i programmatically created textviews and i added it in my layout,but i have one problem.i can't padding between my textviews.this is a my source

```
private class DigitView extends TextView {
    public DigitView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        // If selected draw the accent
        if (isSelected()) {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_border);

        }
        else
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_border_unselect);
        }

    }

}
```

this is a my  xml code(i added my textviews in this layout)

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_Container_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </LinearLayout>




  for (int i = 0; i < mDigits; i++) {
        digitView= new DigitView(getContext());
        digitView.setWidth(valueInPixels);
        digitView.setHeight(valueInPixels);
        digitView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        digitView.setTextSize(mDigitTextSize);
        digitView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            digitView.setElevation(mDigitElevation);
        }
        childView.addView(digitView);
    }
```

as i said i can add  4 textview (mDigits is 4) in my layout but i can't add  padding between my textviews
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks everyone

Comment: From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html): "Padding can be used to offset the content of the view by a specific amount of pixels." So padding does not exist _between_ views. And also "Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins. However, view groups provide such a support. Refer to ViewGroup and ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams for further information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is the parent layout of the TextViews, you need to create the appropriate `LayoutParams` object for each TextView. Also, you should use layoutParams for the width and height instead of setting them directly on the view.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_Container_child);
for (int i = 0; i < mDigits; i++) {
    DigitView digitView = new DigitView(getContext());
    digitView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    digitView.setTextSize(mDigitTextSize);
    digitView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        digitView.setElevation(mDigitElevation);
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(valueInPixels, valueInPixels);
    if (i > 0) {
        lp.leftMargin = ...; // this adds space between this view and the previous one
    }
    layout.addView(digitView, lp);
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can do this without the `LayoutParams` if you use a blank divider drawable on the `LinearLayout`.

in `res/drawable/empty_divider.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="0dp" android:width="8dp" />
</shape>
```

in your layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@drawable/ll_divider">

    <!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have one question. for example my  container layout has width 216 dp at the moment  how i can count padding programmatically?

Comment: @donoachua you can only do this after the LinearLayout has been measured once, otherwise calling `getWidth()` on it returns zero. If you know it's width and you know how many TextViews you are adding (and you already calculated the width of the TextViews), then you can calculate the margin in between. Alternatively, you can write your own subclass of LinearLayout (or ViewGroup, that might be harder) to do this automatically when it lays out its children.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this:

```
digitView.setPadding(...);
```

[From Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPaddingRelative(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: How does your parent layout look like?

Comment: you might be missing the orientation of your linearLayout. Not sure if this matters. And be aware, that you are setting the padding in pixels!

Comment: and as ci_ pointed out, this is not for adding space between two views.